# What is the system APK that handles the calls in ICS?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, calls, apk, system, greenify

I'm trying to figure out what system APK handles the calls in Android ICS? I've found that Messaging is the one for SMS, but what is for phone calls?

The reason I'm asking is because I'm adding them to Greenify. Since Greenify has a feature that wakes them up whenever there's an SMS or call, I want them hibernated when not in use since I don't text or call often.

Comment: Is it the default dialer.apk you are using or a custom (HTC/Samsung) etc one? Also, would greenify make any difference to something that doesn't run unless there is a broadcast received ala SMS or incoming/outgoing call? I'm not sure, hence the question, but I would have thought in this case unhibernating, receiving text/call and hibernating again would have a higher overhead than just leaving it in this specific case.

Comment: I'm using MIUI that is based on ICS. I tried Greenifying the Phone app but that doesn't seem to be it. I'm not sure if it makes any difference but I'm still doing it just in case. I've got a pretty old phone so the more I save the better.